# how to make image scrollable horizontally with 100% width of container

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, scrollbar

**I want to make a div which is scrollable in x axis and want to render the images with 100% of containers width and scrollable such that a single image will appear in containers view**

[image]
**but I ended up rendering all images in screen view**

this is my code
[image]

**I want all images scrollable but with image width having containers width**

Comment: Do you need to scroll the images like a Slider, that's what you mean?

Comment: actually yeah i need to scroll the images like a slider

Answer (score 0):

Add this to each direct children     `flex: 0 0 100%;`

And this to parent

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: nowrap;  // this may be the default
overflow: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the sollution of my question here when using horizontal scrolling it is not necessary to use flex for aligning content in row we can simply style our scrollable container with

```
white-space: nowrap
```

and the each element of container with

```
display : inline-block
```

> this solved my problem